# Match both shift keys being pressed in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

One of my keyboards has a larger Shift key where my pipe/backslash key normally is. Is there a way to match Shift-Shift in AutoHotKey (i.e. both Shift keys pressed) so that I can still type pipes (`|`) in the way I would with my other keyboards? I have tried simply `++` but that seems to equate to `Shift-+`.

Comment: Not sure if you mean just left and right shift, or if this "large shift" is something more special. If it is some special key, you can try to get its scan code (SC) or virtual key code (VK). Here's probably a decent enough tutorial for that: https://jacks-autohotkey-blog.com/2016/04/14/understanding-autohotkey-keyboard-scan-codes-and-virtual-key-codes-beginning-hotkeys-part-12/#:~:text=ahk%20file%20(double%2Dclick%20on,Scan%20Code%E2%80%94both%20in%20hexadecimal

Comment: Yeah I just mean left and right shift. It's a US keyboard and I generally use UK layout keyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @0x464e's comment, I was able to find the Virtual Key codes (VKs) for left shift and right shift by:

1. Adding `++::Send {U+007C}` to my ahk script (right of the `::` is irrelevant here, this is just so that Shift shows up in the key history)
2. Right click the script in the system tray, click Open, select Key History in the View tab.
3. Type `Shift-+` a few times with each Shift key into a text editor.
4. Hit F5 in the Key History window and read off the values for Virtual Key for Left Shift and Right Shift (`VKA0` and `VKA1` respectively in my case).

Then I added the following rules to my ahk script to send a pipe whenever I held the Right Shift key and pressed the Left Shift key:

```
VKA1 & VKA0::Send {U+007C}
```

Comment: Good stuff, and to be able to view key history, your script can just contain [`#InstallKeybdHook`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm) and nothing else. This is what adding a hotkey would do under the hood. Also, since it was just left and right shift we were talking about instead of something special, you should be fine with just `RShift & LShift::SendInput, |` ([`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) is the recommended send mode, but not like it's going to make any difference in practice on this specific script)